# Accessing Properties of One Component from Another gives error of undefined in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to access properties from one component to another.
one component contains a modal another is a normal view page.
when I want to call a function that opens the modal from the view page is it returns an error saying the called method is undefined. This is actually happening because the modal component cannot create an object of modal and returns undefined. I think the scenario will be more clear from the code given below.

**Modal HTML**

`

```
<div *ngIf="isActive" bsModal #createOrEditAuthorModal="bs-modal" 
class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <!--Modal Body-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

**Modal Ts File**

`

```
import { Component, Injector, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/app-component-base';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-or-edit-author-modal',
  templateUrl: './create-or-edit-author-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-or-edit-author-modal.component.less']
})
export class CreateOrEditAuthorModalComponent extends 
AppComponentBase {
  @ViewChild('createOrEditAuthorModal') public modal: 
  ModalDirective

  constructor(
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    super(injector);
  }

  show(): void {=
    this.modal.show();
    this.isActive = true;
  }

}
```

`

**Referencing Page HTML**

`

```
<div [@routerTransition]>
  <div>
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl- 
          6">
            <h1>{{ l('Authors') }}</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 
          pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
            (click)="createNewAuthor()">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"> 
                  {{l('CreateAuthor')}}</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Create or Edit New Book -->
    <app-create-or-edit-author-modal #createOrEditAuthor></app- 
    create-or-edit-author-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

**Referencing Page TS**

`

```
import { Component, Injector, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { appModuleAnimation } from 
'@shared/animations/routerTransition';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/app-component-base';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-authors',
  templateUrl: './authors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./authors.component.less'],
  animations: [appModuleAnimation()]
})
export class AuthorsComponent extends AppComponentBase implements{
  @ViewChild('createOrEditAuthor', { static: true }) 
  createOrEditAuthor: CreateOrEditAuthorModalComponent

  constructor(
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    super(injector);
  }

  createNewAuthor(): void {
    this.createOrEditAuthor.show();
  }

}
```

`

in **Modal Ts** File if I print `modal` object within `ngAfterViewInit()`, ite prints undefined.

I think the **Referencing Page** initializes the object of **Modal Page** before its view is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngIf` in modal HTML was causing the problem. After removing it, the modal works fine